# javascript recursive function returns initial value

Tags: javascript, recursion

Please, help needed!
I'm trying to make a small js compounding calculator

```
function calculateCompound(amount, earning, remains, roi, compound) {
    if (remains > 0) {
        var ini_earning = earning;
        var accrual = amount * roi;
        earning = accrual * (1 - compound);
        var new_amount = amount + accrual - earning;
        var new_earning = ini_earning + earning;
        remains--;
        calculateCompound(new_amount, new_earning, remains, roi, compound);
    }  
    return earning + amount;
}

calculateCompound(100, 0, 5, .1, .5);
```

but after 5 calls it returns the initial values (105 in this case)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: thanks for formatting the code, I'm pretty new to SO

Comment: What is the expected value? I'm not familiar with calculating compound

Comment: Are you missing a `return` before the internal `calculateCompound(...)`?

Comment: But should I? I came from PHP, there you can return from everywhere.

Comment: @peyeruni PHP needs to use `return` too. Without it the returned value fo the recursion is discarded. the result would be the `return` or an underfined value if there is no such return.

Comment: Just look at the function, you are returning `earning + amount`. Now look before the return call, never mind the recursive call... is there anything modifying `earning` or `amount` before the return? No. Hence it will return always the sum of the values passed down to `earning` and `amount` when you made the initial function call.

Comment: Yes, that's right! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The you never return the value from your recursion call, this is why it returns the initial value.

The idea is to have a base case which returns `earning + amount`
And recur by returning the `calculateCompound` call value

```
function calculateCompound(amount, earning, remains, roi, compound) {
    if (remains <= 0) {
        return earning + amount;
    }

    var ini_earning = earning;
    var accrual = amount * roi;
    earning = accrual * (1 - compound);
    var new_amount = amount + accrual - earning;
    var new_earning = ini_earning + earning;

    return calculateCompound(new_amount, new_earning, remains - 1, roi, compound);
}
```